# Ingress unable to route TCP request with Domain name

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have a activemq application pod running on a azure kubernetes cluster. I have set up ingress controller to route traffic to the application.
I have another application running in another server which needs to send tcp request to this application . The application is able to send the request through the endpoint tcp://:>61616 , where IP could be the ingress loadbalancer IP or the Load Balancer IP of the activemp service.

The issue is I am unable to replace the IP with the domain name mapped to the ingress IP. ie tcp://amq.test.com:61616 , It would result in an "Error connecting to amq.test.com"

For my setup , I have enabled tcp routing workaround using this documentation https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

What could be going wrong or what am I missing ?

My yaml files are

Service.yaml (default namespace)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: activemq
  name: activemq
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "61616"
      port: 61616
      targetPort: 61616
    - name: "8161"
      port: 8161
      targetPort: 8161
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: activemq
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

ingress_route.yaml (default-namespace)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-activemq-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: amq.test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: activemq
            port:
              number: 8161
```

Ingress has been installed in the namespace -n ingress-basic
tcp-service-configmap.yaml (ingress-basic namespace)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-basic
data:
  61616: "default/activemq:61616"
```

Added below in nginx-ingrss service yaml in ingress-basic namespace

```
  - name: proxied-tcp-61616
    nodePort: 31453
    port: 61616
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 61616
```

added below in ingress controller deployment file in ingress-basic namespace

```
      - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --tcp-services-configmap=ingress-basic/tcp-services
```

Comment: what ip do you resolv to your domain `amq.test.com` ?

Comment: @Saleh . To the external ip of the ingress-controller .

Comment: That sounds like it should work. Have you confirmed that the domain actually resolves on the server running the other app (ssh and run `nslookup`)? Can you (temporarily) change that other app to resolve the name separately?

Comment: @Max  yes, the domain resolution works fine. I am able to access the application via browser . the application service is configured to listen on port 8161 as well to access https traffic to load the dashboard. I think the issue might be that since I am routing the tcp request directly to the activemq service (through the ingress-controller service) before even reaching the ingress rules, which actually handles the domain routing. That could be causing the issue or maybe I am missing something. 
Let me know if that makes sense to you